# Can I say "Can't greater more"?

Tags: grammar

I know,

> Can't agree more.

I want to say someone's answer is awsome. I think nobody can give a greater answer.
Can I say

> Can't greater more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to use an adjective as a verb which is not going to work this way.

- This is a *brilliant* answer
- This cannot be any *better*
- I cannot be any more *appreciated*

These can be used in that situation. However, choosing a sentence can have many different answers.